# TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_app' Django

Tags: python, django, gitlab, centos7

I just uploaded my app into a production server (Centos7) with migrations  via Gitlab and everything works fine, the problem here is that once I want to access through the browser I get this error on my logs:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/shortcuts/__init__.py", line 49, in render
    context_instance = RequestContext(request, current_app=current_app)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'current_app'
```

The weird thing is that everything works properly in my local machine and I can run it without any issue, the only difference in the server side is that I run the server with production-settings (with a configuration for a production server)

Hint: if I run funtions through url, everything runs properly seems the problem is that every time it goes into the "return render" I get that message too.

Thanks for your attention,

Comment: `context_instance = RequestContext(request, current_app=current_app)` why not just `context_instance = RequestContext(request, current_app)` assuming current_app is a dict like object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out that the issue was because I had an oldest Django folder in my server (1.6 version). I delete all the Django versions, reboot the server and install the one my app uses (1.10.2) and problem was fixed

Answer (score 0):

If you have to work with older versions of Django1.XX and you cannot delete the Django versions and reboot the server and the issue with the render method
you can replace your **render** method with **get_template("template path").render(params)** and **HttpResponse**

```
    # return render(request, 'user/reset_pass.html', params)

    reset_html_text = get_template('user/reset_pass.html').render(params)
    return HttpResponse(reset_html_text)
```

This worked for me without needing to delete and rebooting the server.